# Issue in mapping fragments MVC 3 EF Code first

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

i've recently added a new property to one of my models:

```
public HttpPostedFile AvailabilityImage { get; set; }
```

However, upon doing so I'm now getting this very strange error:

`error 3004: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 32:No mapping specified for properties FloorModel.AvailabilityImage in Set Floor`

I am at a loss on how to solve this, I've never had this issue adding properties before?

Is it to do with the Data type being used with this property do you think? Any suggestions are welcome

Thankyou

Comment: I would say it most likely datatype is not valid for model try using binary/bites maybe since HttpPostedFile may not be one of possible choices for model

Comment: It does seem to be an issue with the datatype, changing it allows it to compile. What i want is to be able to store a particular image against a 'floor', it doesn't really need to even be stored in the DB i guess, it could just come from the file system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpPostedFile is a complex type and contains many aspects to it that cannot be properly serialized.  For example, it contains a property that references the current HttpResponseStream.  This will be different every time you make a connection, so you can't serialize this.

I doubt what you are trying to do is correct anyways.  Are you trying to save the file that is uploaded?  If so, then you need to save the actual binary contents.. not the HttpPostedFile.

Comment: `Are you trying to save the file that is uploaded?` I want to upload an image file and have it associated with a particular 'floor' based on my `FloorModel`, could i do this by saving it in the FS?

Comment: Then you should instead create an object of type `byte[]` in your entity, and in your database it should be of `varbinary(MAX)`.  You save the image data as a byte array.

Comment: Marking this as the answer. Though im taking a completely different approach. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

The framework could of auto-generated a new DbSet with a complex data type. It has happened to me when I'm building models and passing DbSet data types under the model constructor. Go verify the model and remove any complex data types and comment out any DbSet related to that model.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    .
    .
    .
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Solution.Models.Model1> Model1 { get; set; }

    //Comment out possible Model and try debugging again.
    //public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Solution.Models.Model2> Model2 { get; set; }
```

}